# How to handle HTML/CSS font sizing for desktop browsers and mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css, mobile, desktop

I have a couple questions relating to setting the font size using em, pt, px and/or percent.

If your web application is for a desktop browser only then what do you use: em, pt, px and/or percent? If mobile only? If you need to support desktop and mobile?

Comment: Hi Ryan, did you already make some tests and what are the results you came up with? can you share the css and html you tried to use and motivate the reason for your question in case you had any problem?

Comment: I haven't done much mobile web app development. When I do desktop apps I always use px only and it looks the way I want it to look. Sometimes I visit the desktop only apps on my mobile; it never looks too bad but I normally have to pinch zoom because the font is too small because I'm using px only. So I know I can't use 12px for both desktop and mobile. What I really want to know is if you are doing a desktop/mobile app is it straightforward to use the same font size CSS for both? If so and if you're only doing one or the other are you better off using something more specialized?

Answer (score 1):

You should almost always use fluid font sizes.

Users need to access your content.  If they cannot adjust the font size to read the content, then the application is not useful for them.

It should not matter whether this is for a desktop browser or a mobile device.